# System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader Error

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the following to work on my machine but I get an error (Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader')

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace com.companyname.business
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SessionCreateRQClient.
    /// </summary>
    class SessionCreateRQClient
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try 
            {
                // Set user information, including security credentials and the IPCC.
                string username = "user";
                string password = "password";
                string ipcc = "IPCC";
                string domain = "DEFAULT";

                string temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tmp");    // Get temp directory
                string PropsFileName = temp + "/session.properties";        // Define dir and file name
                DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                string tstamp = dt.ToString("s") + "Z";

                //Create the message header and provide the conversation ID.
                MessageHeader msgHeader = new MessageHeader();
                msgHeader.ConversationId = "TestSession";       // Set the ConversationId

                From from = new From();
                PartyId fromPartyId = new PartyId();
                PartyId[] fromPartyIdArr = new PartyId[1];
                fromPartyId.Value = "WebServiceClient";
                fromPartyIdArr[0] = fromPartyId;
                from.PartyId = fromPartyIdArr;
                msgHeader.From = from;

                To to = new To();
                PartyId toPartyId = new PartyId();
                PartyId[] toPartyIdArr = new PartyId[1];
                toPartyId.Value = "WebServiceSupplier";
                toPartyIdArr[0] = toPartyId;
                to.PartyId = toPartyIdArr;
                msgHeader.To = to;

            //Add the value for eb:CPAId, which is the IPCC. 
            //Add the value for the action code of this Web service, SessionCreateRQ.

                msgHeader.CPAId = ipcc;
                msgHeader.Action = "SessionCreateRQ";
                Service service = new Service();
                service.Value = "SessionCreate";
                msgHeader.Service = service;

                MessageData msgData = new MessageData();
                msgData.MessageId = "mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com1";
                msgData.Timestamp = tstamp;
                msgHeader.MessageData = msgData;

                Security security = new Security();
                SecurityUsernameToken securityUserToken = new SecurityUsernameToken();
                securityUserToken.Username = username;
                securityUserToken.Password = password;
                securityUserToken.Organization = ipcc;
                securityUserToken.Domain = domain;
                security.UsernameToken = securityUserToken;


                SessionCreateRQ req = new SessionCreateRQ();
                SessionCreateRQPOS pos = new SessionCreateRQPOS();
                SessionCreateRQPOSSource source = new SessionCreateRQPOSSource();
                source.PseudoCityCode = ipcc;
                pos.Source = source;
                req.POS = pos;

                SessionCreateRQService serviceObj = new SessionCreateRQService();
                serviceObj.MessageHeaderValue = msgHeader;
                serviceObj.SecurityValue = security;


                SessionCreateRS resp = serviceObj.SessionCreateRQ(req); // Send the request

                if (resp.Errors != null && resp.Errors.Error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error : " + resp.Errors.Error.ErrorInfo.Message);
                }

                else
                {
                    msgHeader = serviceObj.MessageHeaderValue;
                    security = serviceObj.SecurityValue;

                    Console.WriteLine("**********************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("Response of SessionCreateRQ service");
                    Console.WriteLine("BinarySecurityToken returned : " + security.BinarySecurityToken);
                    Console.WriteLine("**********************************************");
                    string ConvIdLine = "convid="+msgHeader.ConversationId; // ConversationId to a string
                    string TokenLine = "securitytoken="+security.BinarySecurityToken;   // BinarySecurityToken to a string
                    string ipccLine = "ipcc="+ipcc; // IPCC to a string

                    File.Delete(PropsFileName);     // Clean up
                    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(PropsFileName);    // Create & open the file
                    tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);     // Write the date for reference
                    tw.WriteLine(TokenLine);        // Write the BinarySecurityToken
                    tw.WriteLine(ConvIdLine);       // Write the ConversationId
                    tw.WriteLine(ipccLine);     // Write the IPCC
                    tw.Close();

                    //Console.Read();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Message : " + e.Message );
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Stack Trace : " + e.StackTrace);
                Console.Read();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I have added the reference `System.ServiceModel` and the lines:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
```

but I continue to get that error when trying to compile --

> `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader'`

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1
Professional Edition

Is there another reference I have to add? Or a dll to move over?

I wonder was the code above written for Framework 2.0 only?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What line is the error being thrown on? Please fix the formatting as well. Edit - I see it now I think.

Comment: MessageHeader msgHeader = new MessageHeader();

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct, you cannot create an instance of that class, it is declared abstract.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageheader.aspx

See if the static method [MessageHeader.CreateHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageheader.createheader.aspx) will work for you. Note there is several overloads, so pick the best one for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm stuck using CreateHeader though because don't I still have to make a new MessageHeader() like this (where the first error occurs)?: MessageHeader msgHeader = new MessageHeader();

Comment: MessageHeader is an abstract class. The framework is telling you that you are never allowed to directly create this an instance of this class. Instead the CreateHeader call will create the instance for you. This was probably done to ensure that the MessageHeader object is initilized properly, and/or CreateHeader will return a polymorphic version of MessageHeader depending on the supplied arguments to CreateHeader. Use a reflector to take a peek into CreateHeader if your really curious. In reality this is an implementation detail that your code should never have to deal with or even be aware of